# How to change numbers in material ui stepper to alphabet like a,b,c,d

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

[image]I wanted to change the numbers in materialui stepper to alphabets

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUx1b.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJ1f4.png)

Now i am not able to call getSteps function for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the `StepIconProps` to your `StepLabel`. In your `StepIconProps` pass your desired icon/label in the `icon` key

```js
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import Step from "@material-ui/core/Step";
import StepContent from "@material-ui/core/StepContent";
import StepLabel from "@material-ui/core/StepLabel";
import Stepper from "@material-ui/core/Stepper";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import React from "react";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    width: "100%"
  },
  button: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(1),
    marginRight: theme.spacing(1)
  },
  actionsContainer: {
    marginBottom: theme.spacing(2)
  },
  resetContainer: {
    padding: theme.spacing(3)
  }
}));

function getSteps() {
  return [
    <div className="header__text">Insurance company </div>,
    <div className="header__text">TO BE FILLED BY INSURED/PATIENT</div>,
    <div className="header__text">
      TO BE FILLED BY TREATING DOCTOR / HOSPITAL
    </div>,
    <div className="header__text">DETAILS OF PATIENT ADMITTED</div>
  ];
}

export default function VerticalStepper() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = React.useState(0);
  const headers = getSteps();
  const steps = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];

  const handleNext = () => {
    setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep + 1);
  };

  const handleBack = () => {
    setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep - 1);
  };

  const handleReset = () => {
    setActiveStep(0);
  };

  function getStepContent(step) {
    switch (step) {
      case 0:
        return `For each ad campaign that you create, you can control how much
                you're willing to spend on clicks and conversions, which networks
                and geographical locations you want your ads to show on, and more.`;
      case 1:
        return "An ad group contains one or more ads which target a shared set of keywords.";
      case 2:
        return `Try out different ad text to see what brings in the most customers,
                and learn how to enhance your ads using features like ad extensions.
                If you run into any problems with your ads, find out how to tell if
                they're running and how to resolve approval issues.`;
      default:
        return "Unknown step";
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Stepper activeStep={activeStep} orientation="vertical">
        {steps.map((label, index) => (
          <Step key={label}>
            <StepLabel StepIconProps={{ icon: label }}>
              {headers[index]}
            </StepLabel>
            <StepContent>
              <Typography>{getStepContent(index)}</Typography>
              <div className={classes.actionsContainer}>
                <div>
                  <Button
                    disabled={activeStep === 0}
                    onClick={handleBack}
                    className={classes.button}
                  >
                    Back
                  </Button>
                  <Button
                    variant="contained"
                    color="primary"
                    onClick={handleNext}
                    className={classes.button}
                  >
                    {activeStep === steps.length - 1 ? "Finish" : "Next"}
                  </Button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </StepContent>
          </Step>
        ))}
      </Stepper>
      {activeStep === steps.length && (
        <Paper square elevation={0} className={classes.resetContainer}>
          <Typography>All steps completed - you&apos;re finished</Typography>
          <Button onClick={handleReset} className={classes.button}>
            Reset
          </Button>
        </Paper>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I want to change it  to an alphabetical order a,b,c

Comment: Create an array with that order and pass the pros. Suppose the array is ['a', 'b', 'c'], pass the props like array[index]

Comment: Yeah but it is showing ahead of the labels i want them to be placed inside labels

Comment: It is not possible to tell why it is happening without seeing the code. Update your question with the codes

Comment: You are welcome. Don't forget to mark it as answer and upvote it

Comment: i am facing one more issue edited the question can you please help me

Comment: I want to call the getSteps function to display headings as well

Comment: When you ask something please add code properly. Where you calling it. And not image. Add the code

Comment: Sorry i am new here its my first question i have edited my question

Comment: The problem is I still cannot see where you are calling getSteps and what is the problem

Comment: function getSteps() {
  return [
    <div className="header__text">Insurance company </div>,
    <div className="header__text">TO BE FILLED BY INSURED/PATIENT</div>,
    <div className="header__text">
      TO BE FILLED BY TREATING DOCTOR / HOSPITAL
    </div>,
    <div className="header__text">DETAILS OF PATIENT ADMITTED</div>,
  ];
}                                  
  const steps = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];
 {steps.map((label, index) => (
          <Step key={label}>
            <StepLabel StepIconProps={{ icon: steps[index] }}>
              { {label} }
            </StepLabel>

Comment: Delete the comment and add it in the question

Comment: Not able to add asking for indentation

Comment: When you call getSteps what happen?

Comment: I am not able to call it earlier it was getting called by const steps = getSteps(); now it is replaced by const steps = [a,b,c,d]

Comment: When you call it what happen?

Comment: It displays title in front of A: hospital B: patients C: Doctor

Comment: I think it's confusing in text can you show it?

Comment: function getSteps() { 
return [ 
<div >Insurance company <div>, 

<div >TO BE FILLED BY INSURED/PATIENT
</div>, 

<div > TO BE FILLED BY TREATING DOCTOR / HOSPITAL 
</div>, 

<div >DETAILS OF PATIENT ADMITTED</div>, ];

 }


 const steps = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];

 {steps.map((label, index) => ( <Step key={label}> <StepLabel StepIconProps={{ icon: steps[index] }}> { {label} } </StepLabel>

Comment: It is getting collapsed in comments

Comment: Create a Codesnadbox and share the link

Comment: Okay will share in the morning i have closed the laptop thanks for all the support can't thank you enough

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/ancient-cdn-5cios?file=/src/VerticalStepper.js

Comment: I called the function and it is working perfectly for me in the link above

Comment: You are including two different problem in one question. You should mark this question as answer upvote it and create a new question for the new problem. Because your title says about a b c d

Comment: i can't upvote the question i dont have acess for it thanks for all your help but after calling the function i am not able to get a,b,c,d in the labels

Comment: I updated the answer. I think you want something like this. If you think this worked to mark it as answer you have to click the tick mark